# React: cannot access div element's value

Tags: reactjs

When I press on the that element I want to log it's attributes(value). I think, I am not using useRef hook correctly.

Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/access-dom-element-forked-lphg6?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:0-405

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function AccessingElement() {
  const elementRef = useRef();
  const fake_data = ["hello", "bye", "yes", "no"];

  return (
    <div>
      {fake_data.map((item, idx) => (
        <div value={item} ref={elementRef} key={idx} onClick={() => console.log(elementRef.current)}>
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: similar to html <select> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being seen because all the items are being assigned to the same `ref`. Hence, on clicking any element, text corresponding to the last assigned item (i.e `no`) gets logged.

In this case, an array of refs needs to be maintained, such that each ref in the array corresponds to an item. Something like this :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function AccessingElement() {
  const elementRef = useRef([]);
  const fake_data = ["hello", "bye", "yes", "no"];
  return (
    <div>
      {fake_data.map((item, idx) => (
        <div 
            ref={el => elementRef.current[idx] = el}
            key={idx} 
            onClick={() => console.log(elementRef.current[idx])}>
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the working CodeSandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/access-dom-element-forked-l4ilk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: forgot that I could use the index and find it from arrays, clever

Answer (score 1):

You can not set value for the `div`. If you want to set some data for the `div`, you can do like this.

```
<div data-val={item} ref={elementRef} key={idx} 
          onClick={() => console.log(elementRef.current.dataset.val)}>
          {item}
</div>
```

If you want to get the text inside the div, you just need to use `textContent`

```
elementRef.current.textContent
```